# Update filters based on associations with Filterrific

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, filterrific

In my application, I have `Country`, `Region` & `City`.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :regions


class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :region
```

This is my model where I have the filters

```
scope :with_country_id, lambda { |country_ids|
  where(:country_id => [*country_ids])
}
delegate :name, to: :country, prefix: true

scope :with_region_id, lambda { |region_ids|
  where(:region_id => [*region_ids])
}
delegate :name, to: :region, prefix: true

scope :with_city_id, lambda { |city_ids|
  where(:city_id => [*city_ids])
}
delegate :name, to: :city, prefix: true
```

The filter itself works fine, but how can I make the filter so when the user has selected `country`, my `with_region_id` & `with_city_id`, also get updated based on their association?

For instance, I have *countries: USA, UK* when the user selects *UK*, `with_region_id` gets updated and only shows regions that belongs to *UK*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dynamic menus to solve this issue:

I changed:

```
= f.collection_select :with_country_id,@filterrific.select_options[:with_country_id]
= f.collection_select :with_region_id,@filterrific.select_options[:with_region_id]
```

to:

```
= f.collection_select :with_country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, { class: 'class'}
= f.grouped_collection_select :with_region_id, Country.order(:name), :regions, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true
```

`JS`:

```
(function() {
jQuery(function() {
    var regions;

    regions = $('#filterrific_with_region_id').html();

    if($('#filterrific_with_country_id option').is(':selected')){
        var country, escaped_country, options;
        country = $('#filterrific_with_country_id :selected').text();
        escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
        options = $(regions).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_country + "']").html();

        if (options) {
            $('#filterrific_with_region_id').html('<option value="">(Select one)</option>'+options);

        } else {
            $('#filterrific_with_region_id').html('<option value="">Please Select a Country</option>');

        }

        return $('#filterrific_with_country_id').change(function() {
            var country, escaped_country, options;
            country = $('#filterrific_with_country_id :selected').text();
            escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
            console.log(escaped_country);
            options = $(regions).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_country + "']").html();
            if (options) {
                $('#filterrific_with_region_id').html('<option value="">(Select one)</option>'+options);

            } else {
                $('#filterrific_with_region_id').html('<option value="">Please Select a Country</option>');

            }
        });


    } else {
        console.warn('NOT SELECTED');

        return $('#filterrific_with_country_id').change(function() {
            var country, escaped_country, options;
            country = $('#filterrific_with_country_id :selected').text();
            escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
            console.log(escaped_country);
            options = $(regions).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_country + "']").html();
            if (options) {
                $('#filterrific_with_region_id').html('<option value="">(Select one)</option>'+options);

            } else {
                $('#filterrific_with_region_id').html('<option value="">Please Select a Country</option>');

            }
        });
    }

});
```